# Matlab freezes after connecting to monitor while in fullscreen mode

Tags: display, performance, fullscreen, matlab

Everytime when I am running Matlab (2016a) on my Mac (Air Mid 2013, Sierra 10.12.5) in fullscreen mode, Matlab freezes when I connect my laptop to my external monitor. The fullscreen window stays in the old (smaller) dimensions and has black around it. I cannot take a full screenshot of it since it's frozen, but I can make a picture when I minimize it. It looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know a way to solve this?

Comment: Are you connecting the external monitor _after_ you run MatLab? I suggest connecting the monitor _before_ running MatLab and get back to us with the result.

Comment: Yes, connecting before running Matlab works well. I just connect and disconnect to my monitor a lot when I want to discuss with colleges here. I know I can just exit fullscreen mode and go back to it when I am on the monitor, because that works fine. This just seems like a bug to me.